# Sparse matrix ordering in Python

Tags: matrix, python, sparse-matrix

I would like to implement custom, domain-specific algorithms for sparse matrix orderings. I am looking for Python packages for ordering sparse matrices. It would be nice to have:

- The underlying datastructures handle sparsity (matrix sizes: $10^4-10^6$)
- To be able to handle highly unsymmetric matrices. (Introducing artificial fill-in to make them symmetric is not acceptable; there are many packages for the symmetric and the mildly unsymmetric case.)
- Execution speed is not a major concern but rapid prototyping certainly is
- To be able to define sparse submatrix views (block views) *recursively*
- Perform row and column permutations on submatrix views, which are then reflected in the original, big matrix as well
- Intuitive, easy to learn and use API
- Permissive license (preferably BSD 3-Clause or similarly permissive)

I do not need any sparse factorization methods, arithmetic or sparse linear solvers. I would like to experiment with my own ordering algorithms and that's all. For example, I would like to order a sparse matrix to recursive bordered block diagonal form (RBBD), and play with heuristics for defining blocks and nested blocks, based on domain-specific knowledge.

I have found so far:

- [scipy.sparse](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html)
- [Pysparse](http://pysparse.sourceforge.net/)
- [CSparse](https://github.com/rwl/CSparse.py)

**Did I miss any major, well-established Python package for this purpose?**

**I would also greatly appreciate feedback regarding first-hand experience with these or other Python packages** for such purposes (something like we have in [Recommendations for a usable, fast C++ matrix library?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/351/679)).

Answer (score 1):

I only have experience with scipy.sparse, it is limited in functionality but API is good. You may want to check out [PETSC for Python](https://bitbucket.org/petsc/petsc4py) too.