# Do C++ matrix libraries translate compound vector operations to single loops?

Tags: linear-algebra, software, c++

I am trying to replicate Fortran90 array syntax using a C++ library.  The libraries themselves are discussed at length in [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/351/recommendations-for-a-usable-fast-c-matrix-library). They can all do something like this:

```
D = alpha*A + beta*B + gamma*C
```

for vectors A, B, C and scalars alpha, beta, gamma.  This could be translated as:

```
for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
  D[i] = alpha*A[i] + beta*B[i] + gamma*C[i]
```

which traverses each array a single time, or like:

```
for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
  D[i] = alpha*A[i] + beta*B[i]
for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
  D[i] += gamma*C[i]
```

The first way is much better for cache performance, and I assume is what fortran compilers do.  Are C++ matrix libraries able to translate compound vector expressions into single loops like fortran, or will they emit multiple simple loops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible in C++ via expression templates. Section 1.9 of this [technical report](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-bin/techreports/TRNNN.cgi?trnum=TR542) addresses your question.