# Elemental vs DPLASMA

Tags: linear-algebra, c++, c

I want to use one of these two libraries into my C++ project to basically invert a dense matrix (with Cholesky). Of course, I am interested in a distributed environment.

Both libraries seem nice so choosing between them is hard. Does anybody have experience on them? Can anybody provide a comparison for them?

So far I have:

1. Better support when you have a problem from Elemental, rather than
   DPLASMA.

---

Relevant question: [Recommendations for a usable, fast C++ matrix library?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/351/recommendations-for-a-usable-fast-c-matrix-library)